# Requests python and dio flutter does not return same result

Tags: python, flutter, python-requests, dio

I have python code like

```
import requests
headers = {'Host': 'www.google.com','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0','Accept': '*/*','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br','Referer': 'https://www.google.com/','Origin': 'https://www.google.com','Connection': 'keep-alive','Content-Length': '0','TE': 'Trailers'}
response = requests.get("https://www.google.co.in/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivWlHh9fYSFQ1SYSgdWdYroq7vlNqRWbgzAeOHgb1_1aVO6EfHf9oo4N6kMf9pR-MjgXMeP5EG4VTTeZ5UujHI12znActXxMoyDqKsqI0cgI9YJ_11xd5R0DiKpo2drjWKnK2lNgGSGJYKdDFJ0ZNKhfBTUn3WKSmG72gLR07uPXdby9jCXC1KJFqBSpaGNrJ6Zc6LSQymwNqqJZrO8iwNYRPzJsoHlWUZNSoZ1X18Ii8X7x0TrlgSz0HySJ_1QO3E8LLbaE0rZluLVBsk6t0GDW2MR4IXs3dCuCcTMPDgqZS-CMks6Tgc6xkDLyLLBC051S6gNxRhXpZ3FVg75Vlt_1nAptI_1Vpw",headers=headers)
print(len(response.text))
```

and a flutter code like

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
Dio dio = Dio();
var headers = {'Host': 'www.google.com','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0','Accept': '*/*','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br','Referer': 'https://www.google.com/','Origin': 'https://www.google.com','Connection': 'keep-alive','Content-Length': '0','TE': 'Trailers'};
var response = await dio.get("https://www.google.co.in/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivWlHh9fYSFQ1SYSgdWdYroq7vlNqRWbgzAeOHgb1_1aVO6EfHf9oo4N6kMf9pR-MjgXMeP5EG4VTTeZ5UujHI12znActXxMoyDqKsqI0cgI9YJ_11xd5R0DiKpo2drjWKnK2lNgGSGJYKdDFJ0ZNKhfBTUn3WKSmG72gLR07uPXdby9jCXC1KJFqBSpaGNrJ6Zc6LSQymwNqqJZrO8iwNYRPzJsoHlWUZNSoZ1X18Ii8X7x0TrlgSz0HySJ_1QO3E8LLbaE0rZluLVBsk6t0GDW2MR4IXs3dCuCcTMPDgqZS-CMks6Tgc6xkDLyLLBC051S6gNxRhXpZ3FVg75Vlt_1nAptI_1Vpw",options: Options(headers: headers,followRedirects: true));
var a=response.data;
print(a.length);
```

The problem is that the result I am getting from both of the packages is not same. I want the output of python but have to implement python code in flutter. Flutter solution with any other package is also nice...

Comment: any idea why the output is different?

Comment: "_the result I am getting from both of the packages is not same_" What is the length when using Python? And what is the length what using Flutter?